# Compiled app not opening

Tags: android, android-layout

I was trying to compile an android app to get battery information from device.
App successfully compiles but when I use it on a device it doesn't open.

Code I used is following:

```
package com.nitin.batteryinfo;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView batLevel;
    private TextView voltage;
    private TextView temp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView batLevel = findViewById (R.id.batLevelView);
    TextView voltage = findViewById(R.id.voltView);
    TextView temp = findViewById(R.id.tempView);
    registerReceiver(this.batinf, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}
private BroadcastReceiver batinf = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
        int volt = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE,0);
        int temps = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,0);
        batLevel.setText("Battery Status:"+String.valueOf(level)+"%");
        voltage.setText("Battery Voltage:"+String.valueOf(volt));
        double t = (double) temps/10;
        temp.setText("Battery Temp:"+ String.valueOf(t));
    }
};}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't open" mean?

Comment: plz share with us the logs of the app.

Comment: It doesn't open means it doesn't shows the layout I prepared. It just shows a flash without displaying any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install the APK file and getting error while installing app, then that may be because you are using app-debug.apk instead of app-release.apk.

You need to create app-release.apk by generating signed APK

Comment: I am running (Shift+F10) the app to the mobile through Android Studio...